# binning of long format dataframe in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a long format dataframe representing values for a number of animals under a number of conditions over time.
Now I would like to apply binning in order to average the values for a number of time points while keeping animals and conditions separate.

I tried a lengthy sequence of `unstack`, `groupby` and `stack` operations but figured there should be a concise way to do this?

Basically, I would like to go from the table on the left to the table on the right:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time=np.array([1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,5,6,7,8,7,8])
animal=np.array([1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2])
condition=np.array(['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b'])
val=np.random.random(16)

df=pd.DataFrame({'time':time,'animal':animal,'condition':condition,'val':val})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) with `groupby`:

```
bins = [0, 4, 9]
labels=['1-4','5-8']
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['time'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
print (df)
    animal condition  time       val  bin
0        1         a     1  0.394700  1-4
1        1         b     2  0.492167  1-4
2        2         a     1  0.402880  1-4
3        2         b     2  0.354298  1-4
4        1         a     3  0.500614  1-4
5        1         b     4  0.445177  1-4
6        2         a     3  0.090433  1-4
7        2         b     4  0.273563  1-4
8        1         a     5  0.943477  5-8
9        1         b     6  0.026545  5-8
10       2         a     5  0.039999  5-8
11       2         b     6  0.283140  5-8
12       1         a     7  0.582344  5-8
13       1         b     8  0.990893  5-8
14       2         a     7  0.992642  5-8
15       2         b     8  0.993117  5-8

print (df.groupby(['bin','animal','condition'], as_index=False).val.mean())
   bin  animal condition       val
0  1-4       1         a  0.447657
1  1-4       1         b  0.468672
2  1-4       2         a  0.246657
3  1-4       2         b  0.313931
4  5-8       1         a  0.762911
5  5-8       1         b  0.508719
6  5-8       2         a  0.516320
7  5-8       2         b  0.638129
```

Solution without creating new column:

```
print (df.groupby([pd.cut(df['time'], 
                   bins=[0, 4, 9], 
                   labels=['1-4','5-8']), 'animal','condition'])
         .val.mean().reset_index())
```